# accessing members of a templated class with variable numbers of templated arguments

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction

I have a templated class with variable numbers of templated arguments. As in these cases (I cannot afford C++11) a good practice is to create a default class that we call `none` and put it as default like below.

```
struct none {};

template<class T1=none, T2=none, T3=none>
class A{

   template<class T>
   double extract() { return none();}

   template<>
   double extract<T1>() { return m1_();}

   template<>
   double extract<T2>() { return m2_();}

   template<>
   double extract<T3> () { return m3_();}

   T1 m1_;
   T2 m2_;
   T3 m3_;
};
```

At this stage  I don't know how to implement a generic/templated accessor function that can access each of the templated argument.

All of the templated arguments are different so I specialized A::extract() for each of the  templated arguments.

Is there any better way to do this? Any sort of tagging I can have a look at?

Comment: If `T1` and `T2` are the same type, then this method of access becomes ambiguous.

Comment: This would benefit from [is_same](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) so much..

Comment: Use boost::tuples http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_users_guide.html

Comment: Does this even work? You cannot put explicit specializations in a class scope.

Comment: @n.m. I believe this is just pseudocode. Also calling extract() for the generic case fails (return value)

Comment: Call it a "class template". BTW C++11 is free.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct none {};

template <class T, class N>
class Holder : public N
{
  protected:
    T m;
    typedef Holder<T, N> First;
    double extractP(T*) { return m(); }
    template <class X> double extractP(X*) {
      return this->N::extractP(static_cast<X*>(0));
    }
};

template <class T>
class Holder<T, none>
{
  protected:
    T m;
    typedef Holder<T, none> First;
    double extractP(T*) { return m(); }
    template <class X> none extractP(X*) {
      return none();
    }
};



template <class T1 = none, class T2 = none, class T3 = none>
class A : Holder<T1, Holder<T2, Holder<T3, none> > >
{
  public:
    template <class T> double extract() {
      return this->extractP(static_cast<T*>(0));
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A similarly-named solution to n.m but more on the Boost's [Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost/variant.html) class design.

The suggestion is to use a `Variant` container (a generic container for your objects) and use accessors directly on them.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;


class BaseHolder
{
public:
  virtual ~BaseHolder(){}
  virtual BaseHolder* clone() const = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class HoldData : public BaseHolder
{
public:
  HoldData(const T& t_) : t(t_){}

  virtual BaseHolder* clone() const {
    return new HoldData<T>(t);
  }

  T getData() {
      return t;
  }

private:
  T t;
};


class Variant
{
public:

  Variant() : data(0) {}

  template<typename T>
  Variant(const T& t) : data(new HoldData<T>(t)){}

  Variant(const Variant& other) : data(other.data ? other.data->clone() : 0) {}
  ~Variant(){delete data;}

  template<typename T>
  T getData() {
      return ((HoldData<T>*)data)->getData();
  }

private:
  BaseHolder* data;

private:
  Variant& operator=(const Variant& other) { return *this;} // Not allowed
};

struct none {};

class Container{
public:
    Container() : m1_(0), m2_(0), m3_(0){}
    ~Container() {
        if(m1_)
            delete m1_;
        if(m2_)
            delete m1_;
        if(m3_)
            delete m1_;
    }

    none extract() { return none();}

    template<typename T>
    void insertM1(T obj) {
        m1_ = new Variant(obj);
    }

    template<typename T>
    T extractM1() {
        if(m1_ != 0)
            return m1_->getData<T>();
        else
            throw std::runtime_error("Element not set");
    }

    // TODO: implement m2 and m3

    Variant *m1_;
    Variant *m2_;
    Variant *m3_;
};

int main() {

    Container obj;

    char M1 = 'Z';
    obj.insertM1(M1);

    char extractedM1 = obj.extractM1<char>();
    cout << extractedM1;

    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/BaCWSV

Answer (score 0):

Your class seems to mimic [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple), which, unfortunately for you, was added in C++11. The good news is that you can use [`boost::tuple`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_users_guide.html) instead.

As an example of usage:

```
boost::tuple<std::string, double> t = boost::make_tuple("John Doe", 4.815162342);
std::cout << boost::get<0>(t) << '\n';
std::cout << boost::get<1>(t) << '\n';
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3871f90d5c66009d)

Comment: This is an access by index though, not by type.

Comment: @MatthieuM. The type is fixed at compilation, therefore it works also to index by type.

Comment: It's less a matter of whether it works and more a matter of the interface you wish to expose to the user. If you expose indices, then they have to always remember the mapping index <-> type which is slightly unwieldy.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I don't know what interface you are talking about, since the only interface exposed here is the one of `boost::tuple`, and you are definitely not going to change that one.

Comment: @Jefffrey: He's [quite rightly] pointing out that the OP wants to access by type, not by index, and that your response to that does not take into consideration the unwieldiness of having to do the type<->index mapping yourself in your head.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Oh yeah, I didn't consider that bourden. How silly of me.

Answer (score 0):

Without access to C++11, it's a bit uglier, but you can leverage Boost.Tuple:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>

template <size_t I, typename T, typename U>
struct AccessImpl;

template <size_t I, typename T, typename U>
struct AccessImpl {
    template <typename Tuple>
    static T& impl(Tuple& tuple) {
        typedef typename ::boost::tuples::element<I+1, Tuple>::type Next;
        return AccessImpl<I+1, T, Next>::impl(tuple);
    }
};

template <size_t I, typename T>
struct AccessImpl<I, T, T> {
    template <typename Tuple>
    static T& impl(Tuple& tuple) { return boost::get<I>(tuple); }
};

template <typename T, typename Tuple>
T& access(Tuple& tuple) {
    typedef typename ::boost::tuples::element<0, Tuple>::type Head;
    return AccessImpl<0, T, Head>::impl(tuple);
}

int main() {
    boost::tuples::tuple<char, int, std::string> example('a', 1, "Hello, World!");
    std::cout << access<std::string>(example) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

This, as expected, [prints "Hello, World!"](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e82a49709d34352).